# Can I acquire French citizenship through my father if he passed away?

Tags: france, citizenship, french-citizens, nationality

I am 26 years old and I born in Djibouti and my father was born before the independence. I found out that my parents was a French citizens while Djibouti was still colonized by France but my mother changed her French nationality to Djiboutian nationality  in  1989 but my father didn't changed his till today and he was living in Djibouti at the time of independence, according to my mother, she said he even went to France once with that passport and still it has the stamp. I have that passport and his French ID card which has a date I think it is issued date, 7 September 1973. My question is, can I apply for the French citizenship through him? Sadly my father passed away.

Comment: It's complicated. Generally speaking, you cannot really “apply” or ”claim” the French nationality through your father. The question is rather whether he was a French citizen when you were born (and therefore you were a French citizen by birth). Djibouti became independent in 1977, do you have any evidence your father was still a French citizen after that? For reference, [a link to the law covering this](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/loda/id/JORFTEXT000000338787/) (it's quite technical but doesn't sound promising).

Comment: I was born in 1994 and he had his French citizenship at that time and he didn't even changed  . I have his  French ID card and and a passport

Comment: That's what I understood of your question but do you have proof of that? You mention a French ID card from 1973 but that's not good enough. If I understand the law correctly, whether he was still a French citizen after independence depends on how he became a citizen. On the other hand, if you are absolutely certain he was French in 1994 and you can prove it then you should already be French, you don't need to acquire or claim anything. What you should do in that case is apply for a *certificat de nationalité française*, which will document your existing citizenship.